# C++/CLI DLL linker issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, c++-cli

Ok so I am trying to create a runtime DLL for another application that can be called using `GetProcAddress`.

So I have built the DLL in VS2012 C++ Express (Header and source below) and it returns `NULL` even when dll is in same folder as exe. So this lead me to believe there was an issue with the `dllmain` function. So I began looking through MSDN and found the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/988ye33t.aspx

It states that it is already taken care for me when I create dll template which I did following this MSDN link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

So I decided to try build the DLL in release mode (thinking something about this might be the issue) but I get a linker error saying entry point must be define. It builds fine in debug mode but not in release mode. I assume I am missing something simple here.

```
Error   1   error LNK1561: entry point must be defined  C:\Users\ProRip\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PhantomAdapter\AdapterDLL\LINK    AdapterDLL
```

**Header**

```
#ifdef PHANTOMADAPTER_EXPORTS
#define PHANTOMADAPTER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PHANTOMADAPTER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <system.dll>
using namespace System; 
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
using namespace System::Threading;
namespace PhantomAdapter
{


class PhantomAdapter
{
public:
    static PHANTOMADAPTER_API int open();
    static PHANTOMADAPTER_API int close();
    //static PHANTOMADAPTER_API double init(bool );
    //static PHANTOMADAPTER_API int noDevices();
    static PHANTOMADAPTER_API int angle(double& angle);
    static PHANTOMADAPTER_API int torque(double torque);
    static PHANTOMADAPTER_API int ready();
};
public ref class SerialPort
{
private:
    static System::IO::Ports::SerialPort^ p1;
public:
    static int openPort();
    static void closePort();
    static int read();
    static void send(Byte data);
    static int check();
};
```

}

**Source**

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PhantomAdapter.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;



namespace PhantomAdapter
{

    int PhantomAdapter::open()
    {
        int flag=0;

        flag=SerialPort::openPort();
        return flag;

    }

    int PhantomAdapter::close()
    {
        SerialPort::closePort();

        return 1;
    }

    int PhantomAdapter::angle(double& angle)
    {
        SerialPort::send(0x82);
        angle = (SerialPort::read() * 255) + (SerialPort::read());
        angle = angle*(6.2832/512);

        return 1;
    }

    int PhantomAdapter::torque(double torque)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int PhantomAdapter::ready()
    {
        return SerialPort::check();
    }

    int SerialPort::openPort()
    {       
        bool check=0;
        p1 = gcnew System::IO::Ports::SerialPort();

        p1->BaudRate = 57600;
        p1->PortName = "COM3";
        if(p1->IsOpen)
          return 0;
        else {
            p1->Open();
            return 1;
        }

    }

    int SerialPort::check()
    {
        array<String^>^ serialPorts = nullptr;
        int flag=0;
        serialPorts = p1->GetPortNames();

        for each(String^ port in serialPorts)
        {
            if(port=="COM3")
                flag=1;             
        }

        return flag;
    }

    void SerialPort::closePort()
    {
        p1->Close();
    }

    void SerialPort::send(Byte data)
    {
         array<unsigned char>^ buffer = gcnew array<Byte>(1);

        buffer[0] = (char)data;
        p1->Write(buffer,0,1);  
    }

    int SerialPort::read()
    {
        return p1->ReadByte();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not C++, that's a CLR language called C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

In your VS project, can you check the settings:
1.  `Configuration Properties > General > Configuration Type`? Is this set to `.dll` in case of Release mode?
2. `Configuration Properties > Linker > System > SubSystem`? Is this the same between the 2 modes?

Comment: thanks I just realized that it was set to `.exe` in release mode, still doesn't explain why I can't call it successfully using `loadlibrary`. Do you have any ideas, tried regsrv32 and it says it was loaded but `DllRegisterServer` was not found. I know I don't need to regsvr32 it if it is in the same directory but wanted to see if it loaded it successfully.

Comment: do you face the same problem (not successfull `loadlibrary`) in Debug mode as well? or only in Release mode?

Comment: both I tried the release mode to see if it made a difference but it didnt

Comment: ok, then the next step si to check the external dependencies. `loadlibrary` fails is some dependencies are not resolved. Tools like `Walker dependency` will help you.

Comment: ok so Dependency Walker shows GPSVC.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL delay load dependency models as "System cannot find the file specified" but they are located in windows directory" also `GetLastError()` gives error code 0x0000001c which I am still trying to find out what that realtes to. Why would dependency walker show those errors if dll's can be located.

Comment: system error code `1c` shows as Printer out of paper? I think I am doing some wrong, a printer is nothing to do with what my dll contains

Comment: my bad sorry it is `c1` meaning ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT is not a valid Win32 application. There is something in my project settings that obviously is not correct.

Comment: All good it was my stupid mistake I was trying to load 32bit dll into 64bit application. Wont make that mistake again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a .NET method (and C++/CLI methods are .NET methods) from native code via LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress. .NET methods and classes are not exported that way. You will always get a NULL pointer.

What you can do:

- Write a COM component in .NET to reference in plain C++
- Export normal, plain C++ methods that call .NET code only internally
- Import a managed dll into a managed (the same C++/CLI or C# or any other .NET language) executable by using the `Assembly` class and it's methods.

Comment: "plain C++ methods" aren't methods at all, they are *functions*.  C++ doesn't have methods, and only "virtual non-static member functions" could reasonably be called "methods".

Comment: @BenVoigt And those would not be exportable because... ?

Comment: Because exporting anything except global functions is an absolute disaster.  Non-static member functions require a target object, which can only be created by a object creation expression which involves a constructor call among other things -- the constructor was never meant to be called standalone, and the other things there's no portable way to reproduce.  And then you have name mangling issues.  Just don't try to export member functions.  The way to call virtual member functions from outside C++ is using the vtable (covered by your COM component bullet).